# Upper limit to number of GeoTiff tiles?

Tags: python, gdal

I'm using the GDAL SWIG python bindings to create a new GeoTiff raster for use in a blockwise exponential-decay function.

```
kernel_size = 177764054
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
kernel_dataset = driver.Create(
    kernel_uri.encode('utf-8'), kernel_size, kernel_size, 1,
    gdal.GDT_Float32, options=[
        'TILED=YES', 'BLOCKXSIZE=1024',
        'BLOCKYSIZE=1024'])

# Make some kind of geotransform, it doesn't matter what but
# will make GIS libraries behave better if it's all defined
kernel_dataset.SetGeoTransform([444720, 30, 0, 3751320, 0, -30])
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.SetUTM(11, 1)
srs.SetWellKnownGeogCS('NAD27')
kernel_dataset.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())

kernel_band = kernel_dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
kernel_band.SetNoDataValue(-9999)

ERROR 1: TIFFNumberOfTiles:Integer overflow in TIFFNumberOfTiles
ERROR 1: GTiffDataset::Crystalize:No space for tile arrays
ERROR 1: TIFFNumberOfTiles:Integer overflow in TIFFNumberOfTiles
ERROR 1: TIFFReadDirectory:Cannot handle zero number of tiles
ERROR 1: TIFFNumberOfTiles:Integer overflow in TIFFNumberOfTiles
ERROR 1: TIFFWriteEncodedTile:No space for tile arrays
ERROR 1: /Users/jdouglass/Documents/habitat_quality_workspace/tmp/tmpvUVuqu, band 1: An error occured while writing a dirty block
ERROR 1: TIFFNumberOfTiles:Integer overflow in TIFFNumberOfTiles
ERROR 1: TIFFWriteEncodedTile:No space for tile arrays
...
```

Until finally:

```
More than 1000 errors or warnings have been reported. No more will be reported from now.
```

Admittedly, this is a very, very large raster (`177,764,054^2` = 3.1600059e+16 pixels), which would also mean that there are a massive number of blocks (about 30,136,265,604).

Is the upper-bound of the number of blocks really `2^32` (4,294,967,296), represented by a 32-bit integer?  Is there any way around this apparent limitation other than to just use very, very large blocks?  Am I misusing my dataset creation options?

**EDIT:**

- This raster is a convenient way to store the 2D kernel to a memory-efficient raster convolution (an input to [`pygeoprocessing.convolve_2d_uri`](https://bitbucket.org/richpsharp/pygeoprocessing/src/68003451c1da7cf6207c2c45d477848d01a3131e/pygeoprocessing/geoprocessing.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#geoprocessing.py-2993)).
- The particular projection doesn't matter to me, but it is useful in that QGIS doesn't complain when the kernel (usually a kernel smaller than this!) is visualized so long as a projection is defined.
- According to the [GDAL GeoTiff format documentation](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html), `BigTiff=IF_NEEDED` is supposed to be a default option in GDAL>=1.6.0, yet even when I specify `BIGTIFF=YES` as a creation option, I still get the same GDAL errors.

Comment: A 112 petabyte image?  In NAD27? Yes, I'm afraid you are misusing the creation options, but only by attempting to use them in the first place.  If you edit the question to explain what you're trying to accomplish, maybe we can help find a more practical solution.

Comment: BigTIFF should support images up to 16000 petabytes and block offsets represented by 64 bit integers http://bigtiff.org/ but perhaps libtiff or GDAL has not been tuned to really create so big images. I suppose that GDAL knows automatically to switch into BigTIFF with your image size http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html.

Comment: I've just updated the question to address both of your questions.  Thanks for your input!